# Comparing user's decimal input with c# decimal amount

Tags: javascript, c#, decimal, type-conversion

We store money/currency amounts in database, like four digits after the decimal point: e.g. `12.8665`

Lets say I have an `Order` class in c# that have two properties:

```
decimal TotalAmountDue;
decimal UserInput.
```

All the amounts on a web page are display like `totalAmountDue.toFixed(2)`. That means `12.87` is displayed to the user. User types a number `12.87` on a web form. When I compare in c# `UserInput >= TotalAmountDue`, it does not return true of course because no conversion equivalent to `toFixed` has been performed in c#.

Q1. How can this conversion be done so I can compare two decimals?

Q2. Is this a bad idea to store 4 digits after decimal in db since we only display 2 to the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilise

```
 Math.Round(yourValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

unless currency.

If you only ever require 2 decimal places, why store more than that. Unless currency.

Comment: Thanks. These amounts are basically prices. what does MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero mean?

Comment: It is how you typically round up. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply round the decimal to two digits with

```
Math.Round(fourDigitDecimal, 2)
```

and compare it afterwards with your two digit decimal.